# Vim: Indent with one space (not shiftwidth spaces)

Tags: vim

The default VIM indentation commands indent by shiftwidth spaces

e.g.

```
>>   Indent line by shiftwidth spaces
<<   De-indent line by shiftwidth spaces
```

Is there any way to indent with one or n (where n != shiftwidth) space(s)?

One way to do that is to vertically select a column in the block with `Ctrl+V` then, `I` to insert vertically and then type a `space` and `<Esc>`. But is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid changing `sw`? That's what it's there fore.

Comment: In visual line selection, `{count}>` will indent by `{count}*'shiftwidth'`, whereas in normal mode, `{count}` is used to count lines that are indented. Perhaps this is what you want. Note that same for visual block selection, but spacing is inserted before first column of block instead of start of line.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a better way. But, there are a *few* ways that you could do it (that I can think of anyway)...

**Your Visual Block Solution**

Like you said: press `Ctl-V` select the lines you want, press `I` to insert, and enter the number of spaces.

**Search**

Similar to the above but a little more flexible - you can use with with the 'select paragraph' `vip` command, or any range really: press `v` or `vip` or what have you to select the range, and the type `:s/^/{n spaces}` where {n spaces} is the number of spaces you want to insert.

Its a little more verbose, but works pretty well for pretty much any range. Heck, if you wanted to do the whole file you could do `Ctl-A` (OS dependent) and indent the whole file (or just skip the whole visual mode thing and just do it command mode...as in `:1,$s/^/{n spaces}`

Note that you don't have to include the third slash in s/// since you aren't putting any switches at the end of the search.

**Global**

Maybe you want to only indent lines that match some pattern. Say...all lines that contain foo. No problem: type `:g/foo/s/^/{n spaces}`

Global is especially handy if its multi-line sections with a similar pattern. You can just escape into normal mode land and select the lines you want and indent accordingly: `:g/foo/norm Vjj:s/^/{n spaces}Ctl-V{Enter}`. Little more complicated with that extra `Ctl-V{Enter}` at the end but useful under certain circumstances.

**Use tabstop and shiftwidth**

Yes, if your doing it a lot - I'd do `:set ts=2` and `:set et` and `:set sw=2` and use `>>` and `<<` every which way...

**Make a Function**

Okay, so still not brief enough and for whatever reason you need to do this a *lot* and you can't abide messing with `sw`, `et` and `ts` settings. No problem, just write up a quick function and give it a `localleader` mapping:

```
function! AddSpace(num) range
  let s:counter = 0
  let s:spaces = ''
  while s:counter < a:num
    let s:spaces .= ' '
    let s:counter = s:counter + 1
  endwhile
    execute a:firstline .','. a:lastline .'s/^/'. s:spaces
endfunction

:map <LocalLeader>i :call AddSpace(3)Ctl-V{enter}
```

---

Maybe just knowing more than one way to do this is better than only knowing one? After all, sometimes the best solution depends on the problem :)

Comment: It appears when using the search method, blank space(s) will be inserted at the beginning of empty lines. Is there a clean and clever way of avoiding this? Also I found that I needed to visually select a block, then `:`, then `'<,'>s/^/ /` for one space. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for visual block solution. It's perfect for quick modifications

Comment: The visual block solution doesn't work for me, it inserts only to the single line, not to all of them.

Comment: For those of you who also want to know what `et`, `ts` and `sw` means: `expandtab`, `tabstop` and `shiftwidth`

Answer (score 32):

**Indent a block of code in vi by three spaces with Visual Block mode:**

1. Select the block of code you want to indent.  Do this using <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> in normal mode and arrowing down to select text.  While it is selected, enter ":" to give a command to the block of selected text.
2. The following will appear in the command line: `:'<,'>`
3. To set indent to 3 spaces, type `le 3` and press enter.  This is what appears: `:'<,'>le 3`
4. The selected text is immediately indented to 3 spaces.

**Indent a block of code in vi by three spaces with Visual Line mode:**

1. Open your file in VI.
2. Put your cursor over some code
3. Be in normal mode press the following keys:

   ```
   Vjjjj:le 3
   ```

**Interpretation of what you did:**

`V` means start selecting text.

`jjjj` arrows down 4 lines, highlighting 4 lines.

`:` tells vi you will enter an instruction for the highlighted text.

`le 3` means indent highlighted text 3 lines.

Comment: This is awesome, except... when there is an empty line, it inserts blank spaces. Anyway to avoid that?

Comment: This is the better answer. The chosen answer was too complicated, and in that answer Option 1 "Your Visual Block Solution" does not work on most systems.

Comment: I disagree, because the solution with `:le 3` indents from the left margin (column 1/0) but I think the OP wanted to (further) indent a block of text from the position it was at. For instance, for better vertical alignment of code/text that was autoindented just a few spaces off compared to a better position.

Comment: I agree this is the best solution but it should probably be prepended by (0) navigate to the column where the lines should finally land, read and remember the column number (shown at the bottom right corner in my configuration), use it instead of 3 as the argument for the `le` command.

Answer (score 19):

To change the number of space characters inserted for indentation, use the `shiftwidth` option:

```
:set shiftwidth = <number>
```

Have a look here for more [details](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces).

You can also add that to your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: This saves ton of my time. Kudos!

Comment: 1up.  some of the suggested solution doesn't work as they claim without setting shiftwidth.

Answer (score 8):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could use:

ctrl+V, jj then ':le n', where n is the number of spaces to indent.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Shifting_blocks_visually

Answer (score 4):

Place marks ('a' and 'b') between the code you want to indent:

```
<position cursor at top of block>
m a
<position cursor at bottom of block>
m b
```

Do a replace command such that each newline character between your marks is replaced with the number of spaces desired (in this example, 2 spaces):

```
:'a,'bs/^/  /g
```

Answer (score 1):

If white space indentation already exists and you want to increase it further by one or more columns, then select a block of one or more white space columns using `Ctrl-V`, yank and paste it in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I had to dedent by a given number of spaces, `amount`, inside a vim script. This worked:

```
    let sw_setting = &shiftwidth
    set shiftwidth=1
    exe "normal v" . amount . "<"
    let &shiftwidth = sw_setting
```

A side-effect is that it resets the last visual mode selection. Instead, you may wish to edit the `exe...` line such that it executes "<<" repeated `amount` times in normal mode. That is: instead of `normal v3<`, make it `normal <<<<<<`, if `amount` is 3.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use <kbd>Space</kbd> to indent a visual selection with a single space:

```
vnoremap <silent> <space> :s/^/ /<CR>:noh<CR>gv
```

And I couldn’t get <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to dedent, so I use <kbd>z</kbd>:

```
vnoremap <silent> z :s/^\s\=//<CR>:noh<CR>gv
```